# How to catch empty cell click event in KendoUI Scheduler control

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am using below code to catch the click event on Kendo Scheduler events.

```
      $(document).on("click", ".k-event", function (e) {......
```

But it get fires only when I click on "items/events" on scheduler. I would like to catch the event of empty cell click.

wrote like this, but did not work

```
      $(document).on("click", ".k-nonwork-hour", function (e) {
          alert(d);
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just add onEdit handler in options:

```
edit: function(editEvent){
  if(editEvent.event.isNew()){
   editEvent.preventDefault(); // to stop edit dialog from appearing
   // call you custom code here:
  }
}
```